# GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated

Tags: git, vim, ssh, vundle

I'm preparing to install [vim plugin](https://github.com/valloric/youcompleteme) by  vundle, after I set the vimrc

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim

call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'valloric/youcompleteme'

call vundle#end()
```

then I input `:PluginInstall` and get the error

```
  2 [2018-09-27 10:47:17] Plugin valloric/youcompleteme                                                | 18 " line enables syntax highlighting by default.
  3 [2018-09-27 10:47:17] $ git clone --recursive 'https://github.com/valloric/youcompleteme.git' '/roo| 19 syntax on;
    t/.vim/bundle/youcompleteme'                                                                       | 20 if has("syntax")
  4 [2018-09-27 10:47:17] > Cloning into '/root/.vim/bundle/youcompleteme'...                          | 21   syntax on
  5 [2018-09-27 10:47:17] > error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was| 22 endif
     non-properly terminated.
```

and then I go to the directory `~/.vim/bundle` and execute

```
git clone --recursive 'https://github.com/valloric/youcompleteme.git
```

and get this

```
Cloning into '~/.vim/bundle/youcompleteme'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 15, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (15/15), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
remote: Total 34431 (delta 4), reused 8 (delta 1), pack-reused 34416
Receiving objects: 100% (34431/34431), 32.58 MiB | 2.37 MiB/s, done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Resolving deltas: 100% (12305/12305), done.
```

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113065/gnutls-error-110-the-tls-connection-was-non-properly-terminated) said, It seems the plugin have been downloaded despite the error. But I can't find the `youcompleteme` directory in fact.

I also try

```
git clone --recursive 'git@github.com:Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git' '~/.vim/bundle/youcompleteme'
```

and get this

```
Cloning into '~/.vim/bundle/youcompleteme'...
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

So how to solve this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Recompile and install git solve it finally, the steps are the following:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev -y
sudo apt-get build-dep git -y
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev -y
cd ~
mkdir source-git
cd source-git/
apt-get source git
cd git-2.*.*/
sed -i -- 's/libcurl4-gnutls-dev/libcurl4-openssl-dev/' ./debian/control
sed -i -- '/TEST\s*=\s*test/d' ./debian/rules
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b -uc -us
sudo dpkg -i ../git_*ubuntu*.deb
```

And not use `-y` is ok, `-y` just for skip inputting `y`. The result is:

```
Cloning into 'syntastic'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 27, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (27/27), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
remote: Total 18671 (delta 9), reused 16 (delta 5), pack-reused 18644
Receiving objects: 100% (18671/18671), 4.26 MiB | 701.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (10572/10572), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works indeed perfectly in Ubuntu 18.04 !

Comment: best answer I've unearthed on SO in years. You my dude, wherever you are, deserve a beer.

Comment: upon running 
$apt-get source git
getting "E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list"
unable to proceed further..

Comment: Enabled ""Source code" under "Software & Updates" app fixed the above mentioned issue.

Comment: Above commands made me install few dependencies. Once I install those manually, was able to proceed with build and install git again. Thanks

Comment: This works well! I'm on a focal-20201106 docker container. Uncommeted lines with `# deb-src...` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and ran `apt-get update`. After the command `apt-get source git` three files were in the directory: `git_2.25.1-1ubuntu3.dsc `, `git_2.25.1-1ubuntu3.debian.tar.xz`, `git_2.25.1.orig.tar.xz`. Extracting the .orig. file creates `git-2.25.1/`. Then extract the -1ubuntu3. file inside `git-2.25.1/`. And run the rest from there.

Comment: Helped me on Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) for our company used bitbucket repo.
But last line needed to be changed to: `sudo dpkg -i ../git_2.20.1-2+deb10u3_armhf.deb`

Comment: This doesn't build on Ubuntu 18.04 for me. The dpkg-buildpackage line gives the error: "dpkg-shlibdeps: error: no dependency information found for /usr/local/lib/libcurls.so.4 (used by debian/git/usr/lib/git-core/git-http-push)"

Answer (score 10):

Here's a more up-to-date way of doing this. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2 on Win10.

```
sudo apt remove git -y
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

sudo apt install build-essential autoconf dh-autoreconf libcurl4-openssl-dev \
                 tcl-dev gettext asciidoc docbook2x install-info \
                 libexpat1-dev libz-dev -y

wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paul-nelson-baker/git-openssl-shellscript/master/compile-git-with-openssl.sh .

./compile-git-with-openssl.sh -skiptests
```

Comment: This solved it in the end, thank you! I ran with `bash compile-git-with-openssl.sh -skiptests`

Comment: This script uses 'make install' w/o package management. You'll have to manually remove all the installed files if you need to do so. Experienced on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: This works for me on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This works for me on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 behind corporate proxy

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who may encounter the issue below on **windows 10 wsl2** can fix with a following reference:

```
fakeroot, while creating message channels: Function not implemented
This may be due to a lack of SYSV IPC support.
```

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2465#issuecomment-377583291

```
sudo update-alternatives --set fakeroot /usr/bin/fakeroot-tcp
```

Comment: Thanks mate this command works on me ```sudo update-alternatives --set fakeroot /usr/bin/fakeroot-tcp```

Answer (score 3):

I found an other way to fix this issue when running CMake from Visual Studio and WSL through Ubuntu 18.04.
I found the other way to upgrade GIT to last version here: https://itsfoss.com/install-git-ubuntu/

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
```

Even we still have the GnuTLS recv error (-110) after upgrade, the GIT operation doesn't fail anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution https://stdworkflow.com/652/error-rpc-failed-curl-56-gnutls-recv-error-110-the-tls-connection-was-non-properly-terminated here, I am just copying the author's answer:

The problem seems to be a problem with Ubuntu gnutls_handshake
Solution

recompile git

Use libcurl-openssl-dev to replace gnutls

Install the necessary dependencies and environment

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev
```

> In case you are using Raspberry pi, you will have
> the local problem, you might fail to set local,
> just remember to put `export LC_ALL=C` in the .bashrc file, and do a reboot.

Create a directory to put the newly compiled git

```
mkdir ~/git-rectify
```

Get git source code

```
cd ~/git-rectify
sudo apt-get source git
```

Install git dependencies

```
sudo apt-get build-dep git
```

Install libcurl

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Enter the git directory, where the directory name depends on the version you installed

```
cd git-2.7.4/
```

Recompile git after modifying two files

```
vim ./debian/control # Modify libcurl4-gnutls-dev to libcurl4-openssl-dev
vim ./debian/rules # delete the entire line of TEST=test
sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b
```

Go back to the previous directory and install the compiled installation package

```
cd .. # is in the ~/git-rectify directory
sudo dpkg -i git_2.7.4-0ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
```

Source installation git
Here is just a record of the steps to install git from the source code.

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git.git
```

Switch to the corresponding version tag

```
git checkout -b v2.22.0
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Install it according to the installation command described in the doc document.

Answer (score 1):

> So how to solve this?

By checking if those errors persist during the next few hours.

[GitHub status](https://status.github.com/messages) reports right now

> We are investigating reports of elevated error rates.

And this could be a side-effect of their issues.

The other approach is making sure you are using the latest Git release, which the OP did by recompiling Git.

Comment: thanks for you answer, I solve it by recompiling and installing git.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason 'git pull' was giving this message over and over, 'git pull origin master' worked though