# GitLab clone error RPC failed; curl 56 The requested URL returned error: 401

Tags: git, gitlab, ubuntu-16.04

Using GitLab and Git Client version as - 2.22.0. recently we have uploaded audio/video related files into our repository, currently the repository size increased to 4.5 GB. Due to this now even we are unable to clone it.

The following error being getting while cloning none of us able to clone.

```
githost/tmp$ git clone https://pic-gitlab.com/pic_code/network-mm.git
Cloning into 'network-mm'...
Username for 'https://pic-gitlab.com': labuser
Password for 'https://labuser@pic-gitlab.com':
remote: Enumerating objects: 3695, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3695/3695), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3337/3337), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Error(s) during clone:
git clone failed: exit status 128
```

Tried below commands, however couldn’t help.

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
git clone --depth=1 https://pic-gitlab.com/pic_code/network-mm.git
```

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That seems related to an [old (2013) GnuTLS side-effect](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnutls26/+bug/1111882) which [has been seen here also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38378914/6309).

Check first if the issue persists with Git 2.22.

Then, try and contact GitLab support to request for that huge file to be deleted on their side.

Comment: That issue isn't a bug. The TLS spec requires each side to close the connection properly to avoid a truncation attack, and GnuTLS is well within its rights to warn about a potential security issue. There's likely a network issue or remote-side bug that is causing the connection to be aborted incorrectly.

Comment: @bk2204 I agree. This is more a side-effect in this instance, revealed by a faulty network communication.

Comment: Yes server is in remote place(UK) and I am trying to clone from India. Network side restriction I will check both the sides admins.

Comment: Sparse checkout, SVN checkout & particular folder clone are also not working. Sparse checkout & particular folder clone are required whole repository. Here unable to clone whole repository itself. Any other leads would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Kishore Can you at least get an archive of the remote repo (representing just the content of HEAD, the last commit)? That would allow you to get going.

Comment: @ VonC tried git archive --remote=https://pic-gitlab.com/pic_code/network-mm.git HEAD:Dev_brach/spam_video filename | tar -x but it says fatal: operation not supported by protocol

Comment: @Kishore I meant, through the remote WEB page: is there an "archive" link somewhere (as it is the case with GitHub or GitLab)

Comment: Even in our GitLab repository web (Download.zip, Download.tar.gz, Download.tar.bz2,  Download.tar) download fails in between.

Comment: Since repository contains audio,video files along with source code, I have added (.gitattributes) file in Gitlab repo GUI and tried using git lfs but still unable to clone.

Comment: As per this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52529639/gnutls-recv-error-110-the-tls-connection-was-non-properly-terminated) have recompiled git(git-2.7.4) and tried the clone but still unable to clone it.

Comment: Yes initially and many times I have tried on Git client latest version-2.22.

Comment: Also tried with Git-2.22 on Ubuntu- 14.04, 16.04, 18.04 LTS and even tried on Windows-7 Git bash.