# How to fix curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated

Tags: git, go, curl, gnutls

Same question as

- [git error:RPC failed,curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50813406/), and
- ["error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60019906), in which Hovo Asatryan has commented *"it doesn’t solve the problem, I have tried it"*, and I've tried it too, and neither it worked for me.

So the problem with git is:

```
git clone -- https://go.googlesource.com/tools
remote: Sending approximately 28.83 MiB ...
remote: Counting objects: 54, done
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
remote: Total 51879 (delta 33023), reused 51879 (delta 33023)
Receiving objects: 100% (51879/51879), 28.83 MiB | 4.53 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (33023/33023), done.
```

I.e., it doesn't seem to be a big deal as `git clone` is able to recover from it. However, the problem for me is with `go get`:

```
$ go get -v -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at //golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd .; git clone -- https://go.googlesource.com/tools /home/me/l/ws/Go/src/golang.org/x/tools
Cloning into '.../Go/src/golang.org/x/tools'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports: exit status 128
```

I.e., even `git clone` has already successfully clone the repo, `go get` still fails.

Thus, I need to totally fix the issue.

Comment: I provided one possible solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59787736/rpc-failed-curl-56-gnutls-recv-error-110-the-tls-connection-was-non-properl