# after git pull: error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110)

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, fakeroot

I use Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL on my laptop and it works well with git. pushing and pulling has not been a problem. no i pushed from a different repository to my remote repository a huge directory. and as i wanted to pull it into my laptop, the mentioned error occurred.

so i followed the steps mentioned in this [GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52529639/gnutls-recv-error-110-the-tls-connection-was-non-properly-terminated) post, but got an error after running the `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b -uc -us` command.

the error is:

```
fakeroot, while creating message channels: Function not implemented. This may be due to a lack of SYSV IPC support. fakeroot: error while starting the 'faked' daemon.
```

as at my state of knowledge, there is no change to understand the fakeroot error or the GnuTLS recv error, i hesitate to blindly try out things that i do not understand.

Comment: This usually indicates a network problem.  Do you have a non-default firewall, antivirus, or proxy involved?

Comment: thank you. I found out that the error is due to the size of the repo (12 G). I will never ever again load big binary files into a git repo.